# Why return sequences in stacked RNNs?

Tags: keras, sequence, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When stacking RNNs, it is mandatory to set `return_sequences` parameter as `True` in Keras.

For instance in Keras,

```
lstm1 = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(inputs1)
lstm2 = LSTM(1)(lstm1)
```

It is somewhat intuitive to preserve the dimensionality of input space for each stacked RNN layer, however, I am not convinced thoroughly.

Can someone (*mathematically*) explain the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The input shape for recurrent layers is:

- `(number_of_sequences, time_steps, input_features)`.

This is absolutely required for recurrent layers because there can only be any recurrency if there are time steps.

Now, compare the "outputs" of the recurrent layers in each case:

- with `return_sequences=True` - `(number_of_sequences, time_steps, output_features)`
- with `return_sequences=False` - `(number_of_sequences, output_features)`

Without `return_sequences=True`, you eliminate the time steps, so, it cannot be fed into a recurrent layer, because there aren't enough dimensions and the most important one, the `time_steps` is not present.